# Unable to Install Virtualbox into my Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: virtualbox, 19.10

Trying to install Virtualbox on ubuntu 19.10 but after using `sudo apt install virtualbox`the same error appears again and again. Could anyone please help me resolve the issue and Install it.

```
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-qt : Depends: virtualbox (= 6.0.14-dfsg-1)
                 Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not installable or
                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.3.0) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`
```

After Running `sudo add-apt-repository multiverse && sudo apt-get update`, the output is:-

```
 'multiverse' distribution component enabled for all sources.
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease            
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu eoan InRelease        
Hit:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan InRelease          
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu eoan InRelease 
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease            
Hit:6 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                   
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease [255 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/multiverse amd64 Packages [153 kB] 
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/multiverse i386 Packages [141 kB]  
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/multiverse Translation-en [111 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [51.1 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [7,665 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [229 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9,424 B]
Fetched 957 kB in 10s (96.9 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                          
Hit:2 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan InRelease          
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease            
Hit:4 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                   
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu eoan InRelease        
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1
```

The dkms status is

```
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 5.3.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
```

dpkg -l *virtualbox* is

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                     Version      Architecture Description
+++-========================-============-============-=========================
un  virtualbox-guest-dkms    <none>       <none>       (no description available
un  virtualbox-guest-modules <none>       <none>       (no description available
```

The output of `grep -i virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list` is

`# deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan contrib`

Output of `grep -i virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` is

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list:deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan contrib
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan contrib`

Output of `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1` is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-6.1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.12.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `dpkg -l *virtualbox*`. What command were you trying to run? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: As @N0rbert suggests, it appears that [all the libqt5* packages for 19.10 are in the universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqt5&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all) enabling that should resolve your problem.

Comment: @heynnema I have used the commands `sudo add-apt-repository multiverse && sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt install virualbox`

Comment: It looks like you may have the virtualbox repos defined multiple times. Edit your question and show me `grep -i virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list` and `grep -i virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`.

Comment: @heynnema I have edited the question

Comment: @heynnema Duplicate files have been deleted but there seems to be another error. Kindly check the output of `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1` at the last part.

Comment: Start `synaptic`. Go to `Edit` menu and select `Fix Broken Packages`... and do it 2 or 3 times until it stops complaining. Then retry installing virtualbox-6.1 (you can do it from inside `synaptic` if you wish, or use the command line). Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Synaptic is not able to fix the package. I am getting the following error. `E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies`

Comment: You did the `Fix Broken Packages` 2 or 3 times, yes? In the left pane of Synaptic, do you see `Broken` or `Held`? Click the `Reload` button in `Synaptic` and tell me if there are errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102139/discussion-between-abby-and-heynnema).

Comment: @abby  status please...

Comment: @heynnema virtualbox is working perfectly but have a look at this question  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195833/hardware-virtualisation-problem-in-ubuntu-while-using-virtualbox?noredirect=1#comment2003200_1195833]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit this file...**

`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` # primary sources.list

And change this:

```
# deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan contrib
```

To this:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan contrib
```

**And delete these two files...**

`sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox.list` # duplicate

`sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` # duplicate

**Install virtualbox-6.1...**

`sudo apt-get update` # update software databases

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1` # install virtualbox

**Update #1:**

Before the installing Virtualbox step, we had to fix some held/broken packages, and then we had to open `Software & Updates` and enable all of the appropriate Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have broken sources. Check if the command "sudo apt update" solves this problem.

Keep in mind though that VBox in the ubuntu repositories is quite out-dated.
You are better off installing VBox from the Oracle Repository.
To do this, create the file " /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list with the following content:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan contrib
```

After that, add the gpg key so it's source can be checked

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

You can then install VBox with the command "sudo apt update; sudo apt install virtualbox-6.1"