# Hardware Virtualisation problem in ubuntu while using virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, hardware, 19.10, hardware-acceleration

So i am using Ubuntu 19.10 and recently installed virtualbox on my pc but there is a problem to use virtualbox.

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, there are some invalid settings. (System Acceleration page: The hardware virtualization is enabled in the Acceleration section of the System page although it is not supported by the host system. It should be disabled in order to start the virtual system).

So now i am unable to install any 64 bit version of any operating system in my ubuntu virtualbox.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your issue, nor what you are trying to achieve.  Hyper-v is a microsoft term, so it won't be used by Ubuntu - but I'm not sure of what you're actually after. I can run x86_64 & x86 OSes on my Ubuntu using VirtualBox; but I'm unsure if this is what you're asking.

Comment: @guiverc I have edited the question. Have a Look

Comment: The message says that the settings of the virtual machine call for hardware-assisted virtualization, but VT-x / AMD-V is not enabled on the host. Check `/proc/cpuinfo` to see whether among the flags you find `vmx` (for Intel VT-x) or `svm` (for AMD-V). If not, and you are certain that the processor actually supports hardware-assisted virtualization, you must enable this feature in the BIOS / EFI setup.

Comment: @AlexP `/proc/cpuinfo` I am able to see `vmx` flag

Comment: I don't know what else to check...

Comment: Still not working? (even though you see flag & virtualization is ON in BIOS): **REBOOT IS NOT ENOUGH!** You must **TURN OFF** PC **COMPLETELY** after you save the bios settings and then turn on from an off state by yourself :) (https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox/256853#comment670778_256853)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with a Gigabyte motherboard and AMD Ryzen processor.

Hyper-V was already disabled in Windows (the only solution I could find).

Turned out, I had to enable hardware virtualization in the bios (set 'SVM Mode' to 'Enabled'

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Despite suspicions and red herrings, SVM was *indeed* disabled in my BIOS. I post this so others may go directly to that.

First red herring:

[image: Screenshot]

svm is present in flags. I immediately started looking elsewhere for the problem, as I thought that if it shows up here, then it means SVM is enabled. This is not true.

I suspected docker has something to do with this. I read that somewhere. Second red herring. But stopping dockerd didn't fix the problem. Even rebooting with docker disabled in systemd did nothing. No wonder.

I'm certain this was working a few weeks ago on this very machine. Third red herring. If it worked before, then it must work again.

I suspect now that a bios upgrade I did a week or so ago must have set the SVM setting back to disabled. This is as close as I can come to root cause at this point.